# Why am i getting 'No Overload Method .createBanner takes '3' arguments?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

Why am I getting the error `No Overload Method .createBanner takes '3' arguments` when I try to call `CreateBanner` using Google Admob?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AdMob : MonoBehaviour {

private const string AD_UNIT_ID = " ";
private AdMobPlugin admob;

public bool hidden = true;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    admob = GetComponent<AdMobPlugin> ();
    admob.CreateBanner (AD_UNIT_ID, AdMobPlugin.AdSize.SMART_BANNER, false);
    admob.RequestAd ();
}
```

Comment: Might be because there is no overload of `.createBanner()` method takes `3` arguments? How it is defined by the way?

Comment: That is the whole script Soner, i've done so much today im just running on empty right now

Comment: @user3790606 Yes, but what is AdMobPlugin and what does the CreateBanner do?!

Comment: Right-click on `CreateBanner` and choose 'Go To Definition'.  This will show you what it expects as params.

Answer (score 4):

`AdMobPlugin.CreateBanner()` does not take only three arguments, it takes five. You are missing your unique interstitial ID, and `isTestDevice` boolean.

From the source code of Unity Admob [`AdMobPlugin`](https://github.com/nabrozidhs/unity_admob_android/blob/master/unity/Assets/Plugins/AdMob/AdMobPlugin.cs), the expected paramaters are:

```
public void CreateBanner(string adUnitId, AdSize adSize, bool isTopPosition, string interstitialId, bool isTestDevice)
```

So your method call should look like:

```
admob.CreateBanner(AD_UNIT_ID, AdMobPlugin.AdSize.SMART_BANNER, true, INTERSTITIAL_ID, IS_TEST_DEVICE);
```

Take a look at [Adding Google Admob Plugin to Unity](http://shaneobrien.ie/?page_id=620) or the [Unity Admob source](https://github.com/nabrozidhs/unity_admob_android).

Comment: Even when i add the 'INTERSTITAL_ID' onto the end, then im just getting. ERROR: overload takes 4 arguments! thats even worse

Comment: Right click on `CreateBanner` and select "Go to Definition", tell me what you see for it's definition.

Comment: Thats virtually the same tut i worked on. it was by shane O'brien. God i just want this too work! These admobs integration is killing me...

Comment: I think I fixed it, take a look at the [source](https://github.com/nabrozidhs/unity_admob_android/blob/master/unity/Assets/Plugins/AdMob/AdMobPlugin.cs)

Comment: Oh my god, these admob plugins are such hassel!! honestly my whole game build now does'nt work.. THIS IS JUST THE CHERRY!

Comment: Look at the answer i added, its that monstrosity. I've been at this for days just to get admobs to appear on my unity game! After that eror it has a huge block of stderr[ ''''' orginally defined messages ]

Comment: Did the original error at least go away? That sounds like an entire different error. Try googling for "Error building Player:
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. " There are a lot of results

Comment: No luck there, when adding that onto the end im just getting 'does not exist in current context' i thought these were public from the jar file

Comment: You need to define those variables, they are just placeholders. Example, replace `IS_TEST_DEVICE` with `true` and `INTERSTITIAL_ID` with your ID. That error means they do not exist.

Comment: Mate honestly, i need to look for a good, proven method to ad admobs into my game, i've went thought like 5 already and none work or they are just crappily explained whih just leaves you there. Really is grinding on me i never give up on things like this, cant believe its taken me this long.

Comment: @user3790606 you could always not put ads in your game.

Comment: @user3790606 Have you seen the Admob Android sample? https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/downloads/detail?name=UnityPlugin_Android_1.0.zip

Comment: I've had a look at it, but i dont know how to implement it? Have you tried this? @Jodrell Are you mad? Why would i not put ads in my game?! Not greedily, only 1, 1 little add at the end scene. but its HARDD

Comment: @user3790606, we all have to get paid and I like "free" games as much as the next guy.

Comment: Exactly, long as the adds are'nt excessive everyones happy

Answer (score 0):

In reponse to cyral:

This is a massive, error building player message.To be specific : 'Error building Player:

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\Max\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Max/Documents/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624/sdk/platforms/android-20\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.example.games.basegameutils:com.google.android.gms:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj -S "C:\Users\Max\Documents\Unity Dev\TWOTWO\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\BaseGameUtils\res" -S "C:\Users\Max\Documents\Unity Dev\TWOTWO\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" '

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/675074/android-error-building-player-commandinvokationfai.html

Answer (score -1):

You get the error because no instance method of `AdMobPlugin` called `CreateBanner` takes 3 parameters.

Comment: I don't think that rephrasing the error counts as an answer, should be a comment.

Comment: @Cryal, when the error is self explanatory, I don't see what else can be done. Whilst your answer adds value, it does not answer the specific question any better than my answer or the error itself.

Comment: Find some documentation and provide a solution? Edit: I see, yes, this _technically_ answers the question asked.